# NSScrollView and content view resizing

Tags: nsscrollview

I have an NSScrollView showing a large document that scrolls horizontally.

I have a zoom feature that makes the document view smaller without changing its scroll position. However, app kit prevents the scrollview from showing some empty space after the end of the document by scrolling the document to the right. I want to prevent that from happening. I believe it is the same mechanism that makes the end of a document view stick to the right/bottom edge of the scroll view the scrollview is resized.

How do I prevent the clipview from scrolling? I have tried -setAutoresizeSubviews:NO (on the clip view), -setAutoresizingMask:NSViewNotSizable (on the document view), modify some hugging priorities... to no avail.
I can compensate by scrolling the document back to the original position after resizing, but that doesn't prevent the view from being redrawn when it is resized as the clipview automatically change its bounds rectangle origin (which apparently marks the document as needing display). So 2 -drawRect messages are sent to the document view when I resize it (one when I resize, and one when I compensate to restore the original scroll position), though curiously only one message actually draws something to the screen.

Thanks for you suggestions.

Jean

Comment: +1 for letting me know -setAutoresizeSubviews:NO, -setAutoresizingMask:NSViewNotSizable that solved my problem.